# Phase margin vs. damping ratio (non-unity feedback)

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, feedback, phase-margin

So there is a well known condition which relates the phase margin with the damping ratio for a **unity feedback** system:

$$\Phi_m = \tan^{-1} \frac{2 \zeta}{\sqrt{-2 \zeta^2 + \sqrt{1+4\zeta^4}}}$$

This equation assumes that the closed-loop transfer function is a damped second order function:
$$T(s) = \frac{L(s)}{1+L(s)} = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}$$

where L(s) is the open-loop transfer function of a unity-feedback system (with L(s) = G(s)). The derivation for the phase margin above is done by assuming that
$$L(s) = G(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s(s+2\zeta \omega_n)}$$
My question is, how would the phase margin equation above change if the system was non-unity feedback (i.e., if the open-loop transfer function was L(s) = G(s)H(s), where G(s) is in the feedforward path, and H(s) is in the feedback path)? I could not find any book or paper that provides this derivation.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a link to a site/paper/document that defines that *well known condition*.

Comment: Control Systems Engineering (Norman Nise, 6th edition)

Comment: I don't think that your 2nd formula is correct - shouldn't it be \$2\omega_n^2\$ in the denominator?

Comment: The was a square in the formula for G(s), which I corrected (should not have been a square)

Comment: I still don't think your 2nd formula is correct - maybe you can photograph the page of the book and post to your question.

Comment: @Andyaka Which one, T(s) or L(s)? Both formula's are correct. Try doing L(s)/(1+L(s)) and you will see that you will get the expression for T(s).

Comment: If the open loop TF is \$\dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_n s + \omega_n^2}\$ (being the standard TF for a 2nd order LPF) then, the closed loop version will not be the same. It would become : \$\dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_n s + \color{red}{2}\omega_n^2}\$

Comment: @Andyaka, no this is not correct. The open-loop $$L = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s(s+2\zeta \omega_n)}$$ yield exactly T(s) in my original post.

Comment: OK that's what's been confusing me.

Comment: Johnny Que...your formulas are correct, of course,

Answer (score 0):

Johnny Que - may I ask you WHY do you think that the shown relation between the damping factor and the phase margin (for a second-order sysytem) would be valid for unity feedback only?

I rather think - better: I am convinced - that it applies to all 2nd-order systems.

That means: For the **loop gain expression L(s)=G(s)H(s)** .

**Reference**: Robert C. Dorf: "Modern Control Systems", 6th Edition, Addison Wesley, 1992

Comment: The formula is derived in the referenced book.

More than that, it can be shown that for PM < 65 deg and damping < 0.707 this expression can be approximated with good accuracy by PM=damping/0.01.

Comment: So the derivation of the phase margin assumes that $$L(s) = G(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s(s+2\zeta \omega_n)}$$...With this expression (and with unity feedback), you can get the typical second order response T(s) that I wrote in my original post. However, with non-unity feedback, you can't assume $$L(s) = G(s)H(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s(s+2\zeta \omega_n)}$$ because then you won't get the second order function T(s), since in the non-unity feedback case, $$T(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)H(s)}$$

Comment: @JohnnyQue You seem to be missing the point that phase margin is an open-loop phenomenon so you just calculate PM for the open loop case.

Comment: @Andy aka The point of the phase margin equation I posted in my original post is to relate the phase margin with the damping of the closed-loop response. So the PM (which is calculated using open-loop data) can be used to relate the closed-loop behavior...it's not just an "open-loop phenomenon."

Comment: @JohnnyQue - Phase margin is defined as the amount of change in open-loop phase needed to make a closed-loop system unstable. In other words it's an open-loop phenomenon that can be used to predict closed-loop behaviour.

Comment: I think - The phase margin is basically a "closed-loop phenomenon". It is true that it is defined - very often - for the open loop (loop gain) because this allows a simple measurement technique. But it originates from the closed-loop system: The phase margin is the additional phase which must be inserted into the closed  loop in order to shift the closed-loop poles to the imaginary axis (oscillation). Hence, the formula under discussion involves closed-loop parameters

Comment: Jonny Que... the only expression that matters is the denominator. When the denominator of T(s) has the classical 2nd-order form form as given in your first post, it does not matter at all if this expression results from unity feedback or non-unity feedback. The relation between the phase margin and the damping is always valid.

Comment: @LvW I'm afraid I have to disagree with this...the damping ratio is a characteristic of the transient behavior of the closed-loop system, and the numerator also has an effect on the transient response. It is not just the denominator of T(s) that determines the transient response.

Comment: @Johnny Que...let us approach the problem from the mathematical side, OK? The damping factor (theta) appears only in the denominator of the closed-loop transfer function. More than that, there is a direct relation to the position of the conjugate-complex pole pair in the s-plane: Theta=1/2*Qp (Qp=pole-Q, defined using the angle between the vector to the pole position and the neg. real axis). Note that the poles of the function are the zeroes of the denominator. There is no influence of the numerator.

Comment: By the way: The 3rd function in your 1st post (L(s)=G(s)) is just ONE example how the loop gain expression might look like. Other second order polynomnals (containing a constant number) are also possible: K+as+bs²)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a 2-pole amplifier, the open loop frequency response of which is shown below.

[image: O.L Frequency response.]

From this open loop frequency response, and assuming a H(s) = 1/2, I generated the loop transfer function. Then substituting s=jw I entered various values of w into the transfer function until I converged upon the value of w which resulted in a loop gain of 1, thereby also obtaining the phase at this frequency which reveals the phase margin.

Next I generated the closed loop transfer function, G(s)/(1+GH(s)), from the denominator of which I obtained the value of zeta.

I found that for a dc closed loop gain of 2 the value of zeta is 0.707 and the phase margin is 65.5 degrees.

I repeated the above analysis for a closed loop gain of 4, H(s)=1/4, and found the value of zeta to be 1 and the phase margin to be 76.3 degrees.

These results for dc closed loop gains of 2 & 4 (zeta = 0.707 & 1 respectively) agree almost exactly with the results given by your phase margin equation in your question.